# Why is the style = 'heading 1' and others not working in Officer?

Tags: r, ms-word, output, officer

This is the error that I get:

```
Error: could not match any style named 'heading 1' in c('Normal', 'Body Text', 'First Paragraph', 'Compact', 'Title', 'Subtitle', 'Author', 'Date', 'Abstract', 'Bibliography', 'Heading 1', 'Heading 2', 'Heading 3', 'Heading 4', 'Heading 5', 'Heading 6', 'Heading 7', 'Heading 8', 'Heading 9', 'Block Text', 'Footnote Text', 'Definition Term', 'Definition', 'Caption', 'Table Caption', 'Image Caption', 'Figure', 'Captioned Figure', 'TOC Heading', 'Source Code')
```

Code is:

```
doc=body_add_par(doc,value = "Objective", style = "heading 1")
```

I'm not resetting the styles within my code.

Comment: Because they are named with a Capital in your document. So you should use `style = "Heading 1"` as listed in the error message